# Application modules with Pyramid

Tags: module, pyramid, mako

I'm creating a workflow app with pyramid and i'm searching how to make the application modulable : meaning create a core app with sqlalchemy models, base forms with wtforms, and some base templates with mako.

The basic structure of the "Core" app is:

```
    App_Core/core.ini
            /setup.py
            /...
            /App_Core/
                    /__init__.py
                    /models.py
                    /forms.py
                    /utils.py
                    /templates/
                    /templates/base.mako...
                    /static/
                    /static/staticfiles...
```

My goal is to create **1 application per workflow** which will be included in the Core app : it seems possible to do that via the **includeme** function provided with pyramid.

I want to include each workflow via the core.ini file, for example:

```
pyramid.includes =       
   workflow_app1
   workflow_app2
   workflow_app3
   ...
```

I defined an new app called **workflow_app1** with the following structure:

```
worflow_app1/
            /setup.py
            /...
            /workflow_app1/
                         /__init__.py
                         /models.py
                         /forms.py
                         /views.py
                         /templates/
                         /templates/workflow_app1.mako
                         /...
```

And the **_*init*_.py** file will contain the includeme function and will define new routes:

```
def includeme(config):
    config.add_route('route1', '/route1/')
    config.add_route('route2', '/route2/')
    config.scan()
```

When i'm writing a view for the worflow_app1, i'm rendering to a template included with that app, but when i'm calling it from the core app, it can't render the template and gives the following error:

```
TopLevelLookupException: Cant locate template for uri 'workflow-app1.mako'
```

This error quite logical cause the mako.directories directive is given with the path **App_Core_PATH/templates** so my template should be in the same folder.

Question1:
 Is it possible to make mako searching in each folder of modules the wanted templates?

Question2:
 Is it possible to make the **workflow-app1.mako** inheriting of the base.mako from the core app?

Thanks by advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I would recommend is switching to asset specs for your templates. They are explicit, allow overriding, and provide better control over your template hierarchy. This means that you would stop using `mako.directories` and instead use `'workflow_app1:templates/workflow_app1.mako'` in your `inherits` or `include` or `renderer` arguments. Given this, it's obvious that you can inherit from your `base.mako` in your core app, whereas managing the `mako.directories` option is more difficult.

If you're deadset on `mako.directories` then you can add a line to it every time you add a package to `pyramid.includes`.

```
mako.directores = 
    App_Core:templates
    workflow_app1:templates
    workflow_app2:templates
```

Another option is to switch to jinja2, as its plugin has the ability to add search paths after the fact. Thus your included modules can `config.add_jinja2_search_path(...)` throwing themselves into the lookup order. Pyramid's mako integration does not offer this option right now.

Comment: This is exactly what i was searching for: thank you Michael!!

Comment: The jinja option is usefull but in my case of "sharing inheritance" between different apps, the only way is to use asset specs.